# Sharing files over wi-fi between Windows 7 and Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: windows-7, mac, file-sharing

Wondering what would be the best and fastest way to share large files over a wi-fi connection between a Windows 7 desktop and a Mac with OS X 10.6. Any ideas apart from the default folder sharing built into the operating system?

Comment: What *is* wrong with the "default folder sharing"?

Comment: Just looking for alternatives.

Comment: Does anyone have the answer for the "default folder sharing"?  I really don't want to bounce through the clouds or rely on FTP through corporate firewalls.

Comment: Try out BitTorrent sync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTP. Both have ftp servers and clients built in, you just turn it on.

In Mac this is done in Sharing prefpane. [This explains how to do it in Windows](http://www.programmerfish.com/how-to-make-local-ftp-server-in-windows-7/), but you can pick any ftp server you want.

To connect, in either's browser or file browser (Safari and Finder or Internet Explorer and Exporer) just type ftp://ip.add.res.s which will be something like 192.168.1.5. If you have iTunes you can use the names set up (You'll see the mac name in the Sharing prefpane). E.g. Mine is tobylane.local.

Answer (score 3):

Set up an ftp daemon, such as FileZilla's FTP Server.  Not sure about Mac FTPd offerings.

Comment: Mac has a built-in FTP server at **System Preferences** > **Sharing** > **File Sharing** > **Options...**

Answer (score 2):

Consider [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) as well. Dropbox has "LANsync" feature - when it detects that both computers are in the same LAN, the files are transfered directly.