# File exchange tool between Windows and Mac connected to different logical networks

Tags: windows, macos, lan, file-transfer

Does there exist a secure file exchange tool for Windows and Mac? It would be nice if it could communicate via local network (e.g. WiFi), but with one important caveat: we have two routers connected via LAN cable, one of these has OpenVPN running.

So Windows and Mac machines can be connected to different routers, and therefore reside in different logical networks (as one will be in a VPN)

There are cloud-based file exchange services, but for my purposes these are both unsecure and potentially slow (some of the files to be exchanged can be quite heavy).

Thanks!

Comment: Also: [How can I share files from Windows to Mac OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/279943/how-can-i-share-files-from-windows-to-mac-os-x), and for more ideas [Sharing files over wi-fi between Windows 7 and Mac OS X 10.6](http://superuser.com/questions/268306/sharing-files-over-wi-fi-between-windows-7-and-mac-os-x-10-6)

Comment: If you want to "Secure" the files before sending (regardless of how you transfer it) perhaps just use Zip with strong encryption and a long password.

Comment: [Encrypted file format that is supported on PC and MAC](http://superuser.com/questions/656190/encrypted-file-format-that-is-supported-on-pc-and-mac), [Need simple file encryption for unskilled Mac and Windows users](http://superuser.com/questions/377843/need-simple-file-encryption-for-unskilled-mac-and-windows-users)

Comment: Thank you all for comments. I've modified my question, as i forgot to include one important limitation: one of the routers is running a VPN, so although they are in the same physical network, logically they are separate. The file sharing approach will work in the same network only.